# How to know if there is a space between words?

Tags: words

I want to translate びようすいみん for a manga but the problem is that I dont  want to use google translate or any other similar tools. I know how to pronounce it (biyousuimin) but I  dont know how to seperate the words. Any help?

Comment: You can try typing it in an IME. Mine gave me 美容睡眠 immediately.

Answer (score 2):

> びようすいみん

It must be 「びよう」「すいみん」, which is written 美容{びよう} 睡眠{すいみん} .
美容{びよう} means *beauty* and 睡眠{すいみん} means *a sleep*.
Then the びようすいみん means *a sleep good for your beauty* or *the way of a sleep good for your beauty*.

Comment: "Beauty sleep" in exactly the sense explained by @mackygoo is a common phrase in Engish. Someone going home early from a party, for example, might say "I must get my beauty sleep".